# Calculate field

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello I would like to know how to calculate field this pivot. I wanted to get the average total per each Column.

[image]

Comment: I am unable to see you image that is why i am asking: Are you using avg formula?

Comment: Your question does not make sense to me. Consider rewording. Specifically, what fields you want - show some data and expected results. Also try inserting data in something like Google Sheets and linking that.

Answer (score 0):

Click on 'Values' which is in the bottom right on the PivotTable Fields. There you should find 'Value Field Settings' and then go to 'show values as'. You will find your desire option i guess..

[image]